# Constraining a variable array in MiniZinc to contain all the elements of another constant set/array?

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I have an array of constant integers below-

`array[1..7] of int: diff_check = 1..7 ;`

I want to ensure that another variable array - `array[int] of var int: differences;` will contain all of the elements of the `diff_check` array, atleast once.

How do i go about doing this?

TIA

Comment: This question already has an answer in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984019/minizinc-constraint-to-enforce-two-arrays-be-equal).